# Add bcc mail address to eml file using c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have to add BCC mail address to .eml file using c# . I have tried using below code but it’s not working for BCC and its working for To and CC

```
var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add(“toabc@xyz.com“);
mailMessage.CC.Add(“ccabc@xyz.com”
mailMessage.Bcc.Add(“bccabc@xyz.com”);
```

Comment: BCC is left out intentionally, otherwise it wouldn't be 'blind'.
Still figuring out myself if there's a work around.
Currently working on generating draft mails that the user send from his own client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BCC is left out intentionally, otherwise it wouldn't be 'blind'.
Currently working on generating draft mails that the user send from his own client. Found a workaround for this problem:

I 'send' the mail using pickup directory, from where I can alter the .eml to fix the problem:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add(dummyEmail);

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
    client.PickupDirectoryLocation = tempFolder;
    client.Send(mailMessage);
}

var filePath = Directory.GetFiles(tempFolder).Single();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

//Search for receiver (To) and replace it with BCC since I don't need To in my case
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].StartsWith("To: " + dummyEmail))
    {
        lines[i] = "Bcc: " + bcc; //Replace To with Bcc
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @markbeij, I working on similar requirement and stuck at BCC issue. For some reason, even after replacing the To with Bcc, Outlook is unable to show the email ID in Bcc field. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `);` behind your CC line...

Comment: Quotation's are messed up too. What error messages do you get?

Comment: used the same code in the below link " http://www.dcaric.com/blog/generating-draft-eml-files-from-asp-net-mvc " and added additionally these two lines mailMessage.CC.Add(“ccabc@xyz.com”);
mailMessage.Bcc.Add(“bccabc@xyz.com”);

Comment: Quotation's I missed while pasting in web site(stacoverflow), but in code I have given otherwise i will get compile time error.